# Convert truncated date time string

Tags: javascript, php

Anybody know an easy way of converting  **190304121450**  to  13:19:10 04-03-2019 ?

I am using a PHP framework so ideally I would need a PHP function to perform the conversion.

with Python, it can be converted with

```
time.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(stats[3], '%y%m%d%H%M%S'))
```

Is there a PHP equivalent ?

I tried using

```
    $time = "190304121450";
    $time = date('H:i:s m/d/Y', $time);
    echo $time;
```

but it just returns 23:57:30 06/30/8000

Comment: [`date($format, $timestamp)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Why would `190304121450` convert to `13:19:10 04-03-2019` ? In what unit is this timestamp?

Comment: is formatted in yymmddHHiiss?

Comment: This is from an IBM Storage server and it's how it stores date time information.

Comment: @SorinPascan surely their docs show what format it is? Once you know that, you can use my first comment to format your date.

Comment: @SorinPascan So find out in what format the IBM storage server stores its date in order to solve this problem.

Comment: This might help: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: with Python, it can be converted with 'time.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(stats[3], '%y%m%d%H%M%S'))'. Is there a PHP equivalent ?

Comment: @SorinPascan I gave you a function, its usage and the link to its documentation, have you read what it does?

Comment: @SorinPascan What you said is not true, see https://repl.it/repls/LightsalmonMixedValue for the result of that function in python. Your expected result seems to be `19-03-04 12:14:50` (the format would make sense then too. )

Comment: @Xatenev Yes, I said that the python function works but I need an equivalent PHP function. I am looking at the date function but I am not seeing a way to tell it in what format the string is in (or I am not understanding it properly).

Comment: @SorinPascan I am saying the desired result you posted in the question is wrong. Your date will never output 13:19:10 04-03-2019 which makes the whole question really unclear

Comment: @SorinPascan please read carefully, the ACTUAL output in Xatenev's code is not the same as your DESIRED output.

Comment: Sorry, updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at https://repl.it/repls/LightsalmonMixedValue your expected result seems to be

> 19-03-04 12:14:50

if this is true, this code will convert it:

https://3v4l.org/odPYI

```
<?php

var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdHis', 190304121450));
```

**Output**

> object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
>
> ["date"]=>
>
> string(26) "2019-03-04 12:14:50.000000"
>
> ["timezone_type"]=>
>
> int(3)
>
> ["timezone"]=>
>
> string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
>
> }

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: I'd suggest changing the format to the following `ymdHis`, since OP's question uses 24 hour clock...

Comment: @JustCarty good catch! thank you